# C++ Pascals Triangle formatting

Tags: c++, printing, formatting, pascals-triangle

I am currently having an issue with a pascal's triangle function I am working on.  My main issue is that it doesn't format like a half pyramid but like a curve almost.  Here is my code so far, I will include the current output at the end where i set numRows=6:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double factorial(double x)
{   
    int i;
    double x_new=1;
    for (i=x; i>=1; i--)
    {
        x_new*=i;
    }

    return x_new;
}

double Pascal(double n, double p){
    double d=n-p;
    double fact_1;
    double fact_2;
    double fact_3;
    fact_1=factorial(n);
    fact_2=factorial(p);
    fact_3=factorial(d);
    return fact_1/(fact_2*fact_3);
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    double  numRows;
    double numCollumns;
    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> numRows;
    n=numRows+1;
    for (numRows=0; numRows<n;numRows++)
    {
        for(numCollumns=0; numCollumns<=numRows;numCollumns++)
        {
            cout << Pascal(numRows, numCollumns) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }




}  

//this is the output of the function when numRows is set to 6:
//  1  
//  1 1
//  1 2 1
//  1 3 3 1
//  1 4 6 4 1
//  1 5 10 10 5 1
```

Comment: Using `double` might get you into trouble. Why not a 64-bit integer?

Comment: I figured out how to do it.  I simply used an if else statement inside the second for loop which would print a space before and after the pascal number if it is less than 10 and it prints only a space after if it is 10 or greater.

Comment: If you've got a workable answer, might want to add that below.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ pascal triangle" to see examples.